# Stripe payments api card fingerprint is undefined

Tags: stripe-payments

Having successfully created a token for a card, I can successfully access attributes like:

```
token.card.id            # => "card_1E4YHkEyZ1SEBQHCiMrFatPq"
token.card.brand         # => "Visa"
token.card.name          # => "Jenny Rosen"
```

However, this fails:

```
token.card.fingerprint   # => undefined
```

Any ideas why? Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: How are you getting these properties --- from token generated on your front-end, or in your backend with a secret key? The `token.card.fingerprint` property is only accessible with a secret key for security reasons. You should pass the token id to your backend and do https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/retrieve

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Want to make it an answer and get some points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `token.card.fingerprint` property is only accessible with your Secret Key for security reasons. If you want to make use of this property, you should:

1. Generate a token from card details your front-end using Stripe.js or Checkout, passing the resulting id (`tok_xxyyyzz`) to your back-end.
2. In your backend, before using the token to create a charge or saving it to a customer, retrieve the token and grab the fingerprint (using https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/retrieve + your secret key)

Comment: it works, just copy the exact code from the link const token =.... in try/catch in checkoutSession() in node.js then save the fingerprint in the session's metadata object `fingerprint: token.card.fingerprint`